# 8192x8192 UIView Lag

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm making a game using UIView.
I use a large (8192x8192) UIView as the map area, (the game is birds-eye-view) with a UIImageView stretched across it displaying a grass texture.
This uses *heaps* of memory, doesn't run on older devices and nearly crashes Xcode whenever I try to edit it...

Is there an alternate method of creating a 8192x8192 map, but without being laggy?

Comment: Use OpenGL? Or a framework that's using it like cocos2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's possible to tile your graphics, something involving CATiledLayer would probably be a good fit. CATiledLayer allows you to provide only the images that are necessary to display the currently viewable area of the view (just like Maps does).

[Here](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/tiledlayer_on_the_iphone) is some example code for displaying a large PDF.

Comment: I have a similar scenario.  I have a game in which the map files are stored as giant pngs.  I haven't run into a problem yet, but I am afraid I will.  However, I can't seem to use the code in the link with  my own files, even ones I convert to pdf.  I get an error telling me that my URL string is nil.

Comment: I found that CATiledLayer is unsuitable for game maps... I just gave up and made my own version of it, by only loading UIImageViews within a certain distance of the screen.

Comment: In reality, there is probably no Cocoa Touch controls that are ideal for games...That's why OpenGL and all of the other iOS game engines exist.